# Do closures work normally in html script tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a simple HTML, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function initElement(){
            var p = document.getElementById('pp');
            p.setAttribute("style", "color:pink");
            p.onclick = x;
        }
        function x(){
            p.setAttribute("style", "color:brown");  // Doesnt work because p is not defined
            document.getElementById('pp').setAttribute("style", "color:brown"); // works
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initElement()">
    <h1> Dummy <h1>
        <p id="pp"> this is for testing </p>
        <button id="dummy"> Hello! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't `p` get loaded from the closure? This was constructed using the following example file https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: It doesn't work because it is not a closure. Write it like this: `p.onclick = function () { p.setAttribute(...)...}` and it will work.

Comment: There is no closure here. There is just a function. A variable declared inside a function is not available from outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As torazaburo stasted in the comments, the variable is not available outside of its function declaration, hence the code doesn't work. The following change fixes it. The closure happens when `x()` is declared inside `initElement`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function initElement(){
            var p = document.getElementById('pp');
            p.setAttribute("style", "color:pink");
            p.onclick = x;
            function x(){
                p.setAttribute("style", "color:brown");
                // document.getElementById('pp').setAttribute("style", "color:brown");
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initElement()">
    <h1> Dummy <h1>
        <p id="pp"> this is for testing </p>
        <button id="dummy"> Hello! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in js are function scoped so in the function `x` the variable `p` would be `undefined` (as it's not declared or initialized in scope).  If you declare `p` outside of both functions it should work as `p` would be in scope for both functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var p;
        function initElement(){
            p = document.getElementById('pp');
            p.setAttribute("style", "color:pink");
            p.onclick = x;
        }
        function x(){
            p.setAttribute("style", "color:brown");  // p is now in scope so should work
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initElement()">
    <h1> Dummy <h1>
        <p id="pp"> Click me!</p>
</body>
</html>
```